# Save paragragh formatting on splitting rich text

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a complicated method of rendering RichText using **RichTextBox**.
If the rich text don't fit on a pages, I use **SelectionStart, SelectionLength** and **SelectedRtf** properties to get part of the rich text.
But after getting the part of the rich text, some paragraph formatting is lost.
For example, line spacing.

How to to get part of the rich text with right formatting using standard .Net Framework methods?

**I don't need to just copy rich text with formatting.** I need to split rich text if it don't fit in one page. And if there is any paragraph formatting it is lost. Here is a sample where left margin and line spacing is lost.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, due to the complexity of what you actually require, I'm not sure the rich text box is the correct solution. I know you may have spent time implementing it but hear me out - **your going to run into a lot of problems** here with the splitting that you're doing because in many cases, the formatting for the text that you are copying is not easy to extract and it doesn't take much to realize how complicated and non-standard RTF format is.

**Trying to get RTF to do what you want it to do if what you're doing is *non standard* is NOT worth the effort.** In these cases it is always worth backtracking, and running with some other options. Consider working with a HTML control instead, and then any future features that you want to add will likely be much easier too.

And depending on the complexity and other features that you require, I recommend that you use an existing HTML handling control and just spend a little money on it. The time saving here is ridiculous.

[Try this](http://www.spicelogic.com/Products/NET-Win-HTML-Editor-Control-8)

*(I am not affiliated with this company, but I have used this control before)*

If you insist on using RTF, you will almost always have difficulty with even simple tasks like the one you describe. With HTML on the other hand, a problem like this is swiftly solved, as any formatting can be either applied as CSS to the whole 'box' or to a single element which can easily be copied / extracted.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the paragraph formatting, you will need to copy the format codes, which may begin above your selection point in the text. You will need to find the relevant formatting sections, and make sure your new section on a new page/paragraph duplicates them.

Here's a sample about what's going on in RTF where you can see different formatting on different paragraphs.

From: http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.htm

```
As it turns out I needed different tab sections for the second and third parts of my report. To accomplish this I simply started a new paragraph and redefined the tab stops with \par\pard\tx1440\tx2880 which gave me a tab stop at 1" and 2".

{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0 Courier;}}
{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}
\landscape
\paperw15840\paperh12240\margl720\margr720\margt720\margb720
\tx720\tx1440\tx2880\tx5760
This line is the default color\line
\tab this line has 1 tab\line
\tab\tab this line has 2 tabs\line
\tab\tab\tab this line has 3 tabs\line
\tab\tab\tab\tab this line has 4 tabs\line
\cf2
\tab This line is red and has a tab before it\line
\cf1
\page
\par\pard\tx1440\tx2880
This line is the default color and the first line on page 2\line
\tab\tab This is the second tab on the second line on the second page\line
}
```

Comment: It's the right way out but the rich text is come from outside. And it's not possible to find all format codes. Because of if I get the part of Rich text with SelectedRtf. It works right almost always except the condition when the paragraph breaks on 2 pages.

Comment: To avoid this problem I have to write a very complicated Rich text parser, but this is not a option for me.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF version of the FlowDocument is the only real C# control that allows getting paragraph setting in a fairly easy way. In WinForms the [RTF manual](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm) is going to be a real friend.

As you see in the sample you placed, the formatting of the lineheight and initial indent is set somewhere on page 1, while the indent is set on the second line on page 2.

That is because as stated in the manual that "*the control words (described as  in the paragraph-text syntax description) specify generic paragraph formatting properties. These control words can appear anywhere in the body of the paragraph, not just at the beginning.*"

That means you will have to inject RTF codes. That can be done by using rt.Rtf = rt.Rtf.Insert(pos,"code");

The \pagebb could be used to split the page from the paragraph start. If that is possible in your situation it would result in a break from the line containing the 10. It is poss....

Find the first \pard in your selection, and remove it from your SelectedRtf. That will allow the values from the paragraph to be reused. If you do this you also need the settings in the new paragraph to be copied/moved over to the first one.

Your sample shows you need to look for are \fiN (first line indent) and \slN (spacing between line)

Depending on the situation I would implement finding the first \par before and the first and second after the SelectionStart. Remove all \pard between the first and second \par and insert all paragraph codes I find between the second and third to the first. There are not that many, and are listed [here](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading30).

Comment: As the previous answers this one is theoretical too and needs to write RTF parser. But I am looking for the .Net Framework method that will split rich text right.

Comment: Your post states you already determine where to insert the page break. Can't you just insert \page at your selection start?